# How to write custom "or" condition in "where" part; zf2 ZendFramework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am using following query

```
$this->tableGateway->getSql()
    ->select()
    ->join(array('pu'=>'project_users'), 'users.id = pu.user_id', array('project_id'), 'left')
    ->join(array('r'=>'roles'), 'pu.role_id=r.id', array('role'), 'left')
    ->where(array('company_id'=>$company_id,'users.status'=>'1',''));
```

What i need is:

To apply the condition as following

```
where  company_id=1 and users.status='1' and (project_id=null or project_id=1)
```

I am unable to get this

Please help

Comment: see if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242185/zend-framework-2-sql-select-with-or-and-and

Comment: It worked as below                             **`$where = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Where();

  $where->equalTo('company_id',$company_id)
  ->and
  ->equalTo('users.status','1')
  ->nest()
   ->isNull('project_id')
   ->or
   ->equalTo('project_id',$project_id)
  ->unnest();

  $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select()
  ->join(array('pu'=>'project_users'), 'users.id = pu.user_id', array('project_id'), 'left')->join(array('r'=>'roles'), 'pu.role_id=r.id', array('role'), 'left')->where($where);`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like

```
$where = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Where();
$where->equalTo('company_id',$company_id)->and
->equalTo('users.status','1')->nest()
->isNull('project_id')->or->equalTo('project_id',$project_id)
->unnest();         

$resultSet = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select()
->join(array('pu'=>'project_users'), 'users.id = pu.user_id', 
array('project_id'), 'left')
->join(array('r'=>'roles'),'pu.role_id=r.id', array('role'),'left')
->where($where);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, Last line:

```
$this->tableGateway->getSql()->select()
        ->join(array('pu'=>'project_users'), 'users.id = pu.user_id', array('project_id'), 'left')
        ->join(array('r'=>'roles'), 'pu.role_id=r.id', array('role'), 'left')
        ->where(array('company_id'=>$company_id,'users.status'=>'1'))
        ->where(array('project_id'=>null,'project_id'=>'1'), Predicate\PredicateSet::OP_OR);
```